# Keeping folder display the same as it was left

Tags: display

In Word 2007 (and also on previous versions I have used), when I open folders, they open with icons or a list.  I like 'detail' display and change it to that. I like detail because I can see which file is most recent and the size.  But the next time I open the same folder, it opens back to icons or list but not details. How can I get it to stay where I left it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem should have been fixed from Vista onwards. In XP, you can use a free tool called [**FileOpenPatcher**](http://www.netcult.ch/elmue/ElmueSoft-en.htm) to fix this:

> FileOpenPatcher from ElmüSoft enlarges
>   the Windows Open File dialog (in
>   Comdlg32.dll) and **switches it to
>   Detail view**.

[image]

The tool supports Windows 98SE, ME, NT4, 2000, XP, and 2003.